# Retrieve hierarchical data

Tags: php

I 'm trying to create a dynamic menu for a CMS system
this is my sql table, it has one extra  field called content

```
parent_id  order     id  titel                  
0          1         2   Home                   
0          2         4   Contact                
0          3         9   stuff         
2          1         1   more stuff
2          2         3   way more stuff             
9          1         10  all stuff
```

I want this result:

```
home
 more stuff
 way more stuff
contact
stuff
 all stuff
```

This is how I call the menu:

```
        $resultPaginas = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select id, titel, parent_id, volgorde from TABLE order by order");
    if (!$resultPaginas) {
        die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
```

This wil show the table ordered by parent_id, order.

It's allmost done, I know I need to do a while loop, but how do I perform the correct while loop to get the result that I want?

p.s. This is going to be a menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this recursive function for building your menu:

```
function buildMenu($parentId = 0) {
    $menu = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `id`, `titel`, `parent_id`, `volgorde` FROM [TABLE] WHERE `parent_id` = $parentId ORDER BY `order`");

    if ($result !== false) {
        while ($page = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $page["children"] = buildMenu($page["id"]);
            $menu[] = $page;
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
```

Call the recursive function like that

```
$resultPaginas = buildMenu();
```

Example content of $resultPaginas:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [titel] => home
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [titel] => more stuff
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [titel] => way more stuff
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent_id] => 0
            [titel] => contact
        )

)
```

Comment: looks good, bu what do you mean by $page["children"]? 
field 'titel' what is displayed in the sqli line?

Comment: The function returns all menu items with the given parent id. So in the first run it gets all menu items with parent id "0" and loops through them to get all menu items with the parent ids of those and stores it in ["children"] and so on. Just the usual recursive stuff. (P.S.: I'm updating my answer for an example output)

Comment: Great, when I do a vardump on this function, I see what I want to see, only one question: how do I print or echo the field 'titel'?

Comment: With the same recursive approach. Maybe with a `printMenu($menupart)` function

Answer (score 1):

Try  this  first select all from tables where parent id is 0

and do loop through that

sample:

```
foreach($parent as $par){
//Then you need to write another query to take all submenus for current parentid menu

  $submenus= mysqli_query($mysqli, "select id, titel, parent_id, volgorde from TABLE where parent_id = $par.id order by order");

//Then again loop trough 

foreach($submenus as $sub){

// and add existing submenus to parent menu
}
}
```

**NOTE: This is only concept sorry if syntax is not correct.**